# How can I get the instance of host component for directive?

Tags: angular

Before ng9, I can get the instance by:

Inject the ViewContainerRef in constructor

`constructor(private _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }`

and then get it using

`let hostComponent = this._viewContainerRef["_data"].componentView.component;`

But in ng9, there is no `_data` property in ViewContainerRef:

How can I do in ng9? Thanks!

Comment: Please extend the question with the following. Is this a component or a directive? What are you trying to achieve with the component reference? `_data` seems to be a private variable on the `ViewContainerRef`, why do you need to access it?

Answer (score 2):

If your directive is applied to a unique kind of component, you can use in constructor

```
constructor(@Optional() @Host() private component:YourComponent){}
```

NOTE: You need "wait" to ngAfterViewInit to get the value of a variable in the component